# Subclass UITableViewCell calling endEditing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a Table View that has several different types of `UITableViewCell`'s - one for `UISwitches`, one for `UISegmentedCells`, and one for `UITextField`s. All of these `UITableViewCells` have corresponding subclasses for them. All of this is working as expected, with the exception of trying to get the `endEditing` to be called from the `UITextField` subclass. It is called if I click anywhere inside of any `TextField` cell. However, if I click inside of a different cell or outside the table, this `endEditing` is never called. I understand this is because I am now touching inside of another class, but what is the best way to get around this so endEditing will always be called no matter where I touch? Also, I tried the touchesBegan method - but that seems to only work if I touch inside the `UITextField` row as well. The touchesBegan method is not being called if I place it inside the main `TableViewController` logic either (although I think after researching this is desired, as the touches are handled by all the subclasses now).

Do I need to add a touchesBegan to every subclass? That seems like overkill.

What is the best way to handle this type of scenario?

EDIT Relevant Code snippets are below:

**TableViewController.m**:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%ld", indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *dictElement = [pListDictionary objectForKey:string];

if (dictElement == nil)
    return nil; //if here, check your RunPhasePList.plist file and make sure it exists and isn't corrupt.

NSString *cellType = [dictElement objectForKey:@"type"];
if ([cellType isEqualToString:@"switch"])
    return [self getSwitchCellWithDict:dictElement withTableView:tableView withIndexPath:indexPath];
else if ([cellType isEqualToString:@"textField"])
    return [self getTextCellWithDict:dictElement withTableView:tableView withIndexPath:indexPath];
else if ([cellType isEqualToString:@"segmentedControl"])
    return [self getSegCellWithDict:dictElement withTableView:tableView withIndexPath:indexPath];
```

And later, still in TableViewController.m:

```
(TextFieldTableViewCell *) getTextCellWithDict:(NSDictionary *) dict
                               withTableView:(UITableView *) tableView
                               withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
TextFieldTableViewCell *textCell;
if (dict == nil || ([dict count] == 0))
    return nil;

textCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"textCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
textCell.customLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
textCell.customTextField.placeholder = [dict objectForKey:@"default"];
textCell.customTextField.text = [dict objectForKey:@"userEntry"];

textCell.customTextField.tag = TAG_OFFSET_ENTRY + (indexPath.section * 10) + (indexPath.row);
textCell.customButtonQuestion.tag = TAG_OFFSET_QUESTION + (indexPath.section * 10) + (indexPath.row);
return textCell;
```

And in **TextFieldTableViewCell.m**:

```
(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[customTextField resignFirstResponder];
return YES; }

(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self.superview endEditing:YES]; }

(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
NSLog(@"in here now");
//do other stuff }
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Do you textfields have every cell ?

Comment: No. Only the TextFieldTableViewCell subclass has text fields. It works fine if I click in a cell with a textfield. The problem comes when I click in another cell that doesnt have a text field, or outside the table.